# Checkbox not visible in pdf cell using iTextSharp c#

Tags: c#, itext

I have written this code to show the checkbox in Pdf cell. I don't want to make it interactive. just wanted to show it in pdf cell.

```
RadioCheckField _radioG;
_radioG = new RadioCheckField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(50, 50), "Wage?", "Off");
_radioG.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK;
_radioG.Checked = false;
iTextSharp.text.pdf.events.FieldPositioningEvents kid = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.events.FieldPositioningEvents(writer, _radioG.CheckField, "checks");
kid.Padding = 0.5F;
workOffice.CellEvent = kid;
```

After writing this code checkbox not visible neither in cell nor in whole pdf.

please suggest how can i do it using iTextSharp.

Comment: Looking at the source code of `FieldPositioningEvents` it appears mostly to be made for text fields; in particular in case of your constructor internally a `TextField` instance is generated and added as a child to your radio field.

Comment: Have you tried without that third parameter?